# How to return 'NA' if not found instead of null

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have a database with list of drugs and when I query it I would like to recieve a pandas dataframe which finds the drug and returns its description but if the drug is not found it should return 'NA' or some string instead of skipping the drug entirely

I am not sure if this can be done in Postgres itself but I am using psycopg2 and python3.8 to fire queries into Postgres database

```
current code 
drugs = [d1, d2, d3, d4]

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from drugs where drug in ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4')", connection)

current output
drug  information
d1    xyz
d2    sad
d4    asd

Expected output
drug  information
d1    xyz
d2    sad
d3    NA
d4    asd
```

Comment: Maybe `SELECT drug,  COALESCE(information, 'NA') as information from drugs where drug in ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4')` ?

Comment: I have tried coalesce and it does not work as there is no record of say 'd3' from example above in database to coalesce.

Comment: Hm. You need some kind of LEFT JOIN. From where 'd1'-'d4' comes?  Of course you can do something like: `SELECT d.d, COALESCE(dr.information, 'NA')  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']) AS d LEFT JOIN drugs dr ON d.d = dr.drug` but it smells fishy

Comment: @AlexYu It works..! I am not sure how or why but it seems to work. Can you please explain or link what UNNEST does in this query, It is the first time I have seen this. It will be a great help for me.

Comment: It's actually a crutch: you create a pseudo-table with `unnest` from array and `LEFT JOIN ` actual table that holds information. If you have a real table with drug names that includes values as 'd3'  - it will be better to use it.

Comment: Ah I see I think the pseudo-table way might be the way for me to go. As I expect a lot of values which might not be in the table. Thank you so much @AlexYu for your help and explanation